# SSIS ForEach Azure Files Storage Enumerator

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I know that in SSIS, when creating a Foreach loop container, I can enumerate through Azure Blob Storage using the [Azure Feature Pack for SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/azure-feature-pack-for-integration-services-ssis?view=sql-server-2017). However, I want to enumerate through Azure **File** Storage. Any way to do this?

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-decide-blobs-files-disks?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json) for the differences between Blobs and Files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to mount the file share and just use the normal SSIS file system functionality to enumerate an Azure file share.

Does this work for you?

Thanks,

Will Gries
Program Manager, Azure Files

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to go fully serverless here (all in Azure), so I'm running the SSIS package in Azure Data Factory and there's no access to local file systems there. If I need to I can change from Files to Blobs but would prefer Files.

Comment: @JoshD, according to the MS article you shared, Azure File Storage can provide access via SMB interface. So, you can create an SMB share for file access, and use it in Enumerate Files task, with UNC name. Addition - you do not need to create local disk and mount it to this UNC share.